# Geospatial Projects Management System/Software for multiple concurrent Projects

Tags: software-recommendations, data-management

I'm looking for a System/Software for managing multiple (20+) Academic Researches and Projects.

Due to a large number of active projects lately, which many of consist of the same geographical location, we are in need of a System/Software that has mainly the following features:

- Important Feature: Attribute of projects geographical location (e.g. Search for projects in a specific location)
- Common Features: Deadline / Done - To Do / Project Personnel Information
- Being able to gather each project files in one location and accessible from everywhere (Cloud? Add-on for cloud?).
- Being able to set priorities for projects.
- Bonus: After setting the system up, needs as little maintenance as possible.

Any suggestions for such a software/system would be great. Ideas and advises are welcomed.

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange site where [software recommendations are on-topic](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but it is not GIS SE.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, will check it out.

Comment: The Software-Rec post is here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/geospatial-projects-management-system-software-for-multiple-concurrent-projects, but unfortunately has no takers yet.